# Cannot update volume group ubuntu-vg with duplicate PV devices

Tags: server, settings, storage

We have 2 x **4TB hdd** on our server (hardware server). Raid 1 and use 1 hdd.

OS: **Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS** (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-52-generic x86_64).

But our root space use only around 100 GB.

**How to extend `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` to use 4TB ?**

command `df-h`:

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              1.6G  1.6M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   98G  6.9G   87G   8% /
tmpfs                              7.6G     0  7.6G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                          2.0G  128M  1.7G   7% /boot
/dev/sda1                          1.1G  5.3M  1.1G   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                              1.6G  4.0K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

after run command:

```
sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
```

error output:

```
WARNING: Not using device /dev/sdb3 for PV fMayhP-tuYy-Vbpu-Ba5e-XYjy-d7l2-l6C5kU.
  WARNING: PV fMayhP-tuYy-Vbpu-Ba5e-XYjy-d7l2-l6C5kU prefers device /dev/sda3 because device is used by LV.
  Size of logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv changed from 100.00 GiB (25600 extents) to <3.64 TiB (953080 extents).
  Cannot update volume group ubuntu-vg with duplicate PV devices.
```

screenshot `vgdisplay` & `lvdisplay`:
(https://postimg.cc/vcMRHc5n)
(https://postimg.cc/KRv2D142)

can you help us solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The situation on my end is that the server installation system is an onboard raid, which makes it impossible to add. You can try to separate 4TB as LVM, which should be possible